# Select value form multiple AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am creating an alertdialog in the onClick() and when i select a particular value from the first alertdialog then a new alertdialog appears. for the first alertdialog I am using **if** case to get the value of **which** and from that received another alertdialog appears. I want to know that how can I distinguish the **which** value of both the alertdialogs..

This is my code:

```
case R.id.wlcm_search:
SearchSelect();
break;

private void SearchSelect()
{
    Builder srch = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    srch.setTitle("Search");
    srch.setItems(R.array.search, WelcomeUser.this);
    srch.show();
}

private void PriceSrch()
{
    Builder psrch = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    psrch.setTitle("Search By Price Range");
    psrch.setItems(R.array.price_search, this);
    psrch.show();
}
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(which==5)
    {
        PriceSrch();
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I distinguish the **which** values of both the alertdialogs..
in the SearchSelect() there are 6 items (0 to 5) and when I click the last item then PriceSrch() alertdialog pops up and in the PriceSrch() there aur 5 items (0 to 4)...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: May be this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579963/alertdialog-inside-alertdialog-android?rq=1

Comment: There are different methods you can use any of them. One is at above link another is what you can do is you can add two different listeners for you click event on two different dialogs.