# How to create custom alert dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am developing a sample app.I am able to show alert on button click having some tittle and button .But now  I want to show a pop up window having  **username (Label) and text field (Edit field)** and a button.
on click on button.can I make another popup xml file for that ?

```
public void selfDestruct(View view) {
         // Kabloey
         Log.d("Naveen", "Test====");
         System.out.println("----------------------ghfgjhf-----------------");
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this).create();
         alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
         alertDialog.setMessage("R u sure?");
         alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               //here you can add functions

            } });
         alertDialog.show();
     }
```

```
   <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

Comment: You can use custom layout for your alert dialog. Take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579963/alertdialog-inside-alertdialog-android

Comment: Have you tried http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-create-popup-window-in-android.html ?

Comment: You should change the question to "how to create custom alert dialog?" otherwise it will lead to confusions for other users..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Enter some thing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout                
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"   
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">     

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAVE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Need to inflate custom_dialog.xml**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Alert Dialog");

final EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
Button btnSave          = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
Button btnCancel        = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: how to dismiss this pop up

Comment: on cancel button in pop up screen?

Comment: You can dismiss the dialog like dialog .dismiss(); and get the value from edittext is like editText.getText().toString();

Comment: Thanks..Last how to pass text value from one view to another ?

Comment: You can create getter and setter of your text value . And then you use  YourView.getYourTextValue() in the other view

Answer (score 4):

You can make a normal activity and set the `android:theme` to dialog:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.carsharingkitdemo.YourPopUpActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

and in your `xml` file for this activity you can decide the height and width of this dialog field. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="100dp">
```

The important thing is the manifest part.

Comment: or this can help you: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/

Answer (score 3):

Try to use: [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

You can find example here: http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Dialog** , like this code :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
// dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
dialog.setTitle("Title...");

// set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
dialog.dismiss();
}
});
dialog.show();
```

if you want to remove **title bar** just use this code after define :

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Reset...").setView(editText)
   .setMessage("R u sure?").setCancelable(true)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
        //Do here whatever.....
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is xml code and activity code see it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Popup Window will display on this Activity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popupbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Show Popup" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity file

```
package com.nkm.popup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PopupDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
LinearLayout layoutOfPopup;
PopupWindow popupMessage;
Button popupButton, insidePopupButton;
TextView popupText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    init();
    popupInit();
}

public void init() {
    popupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.popupbutton);
    popupText = new TextView(this);
    insidePopupButton = new Button(this);
    layoutOfPopup = new LinearLayout(this);
    insidePopupButton.setText("OK");
    popupText.setText("This is Popup Window.press OK to dismiss         it.");
    popupText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);
    layoutOfPopup.setOrientation(1);
    layoutOfPopup.addView(popupText);
    layoutOfPopup.addView(insidePopupButton);
}

public void popupInit() {
    popupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    insidePopupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    popupMessage = new PopupWindow(layoutOfPopup, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupMessage.setContentView(layoutOfPopup);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.popupbutton) {
        popupMessage.showAsDropDown(popupButton, 0, 0);
    }

    else {
        popupMessage.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### its working for me

```
Dialog m_dialog; 
m_dialog = new Dialog(BusinessDetail.this);
            m_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            
            LayoutInflater m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(BusinessDetail.this);
            View m_view = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.rateus_popup, null);
            myPopLay = (LinearLayout) m_view.findViewById(R.id.myPopLay);
m_dialog.setContentView(m_view);
            m_dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below coding to display a Pop up in android.

```
AlertDialog.builder builder=new AlertDilaog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("PopUP Example");
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("");
    alert.show();

    new Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
    @override
    public void run()
    {
  //TODO
    alert.dismiss();
    }
    },1*1000);
    }
```

Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEsVTTl6exg

Answer (score 0):

We will use the PopupWindow class to create the popup.

One thing I would like to mention is that we want the popup to be attached to the button that opened it. For example if the “Show Popup” button from the screenshot above would be positioned in the middle of the screen, we want the popup window stick to the button’s position. To achieve this, first we should get the button’s “x” and “y” position on the screen, and pass them to the popup window. Then will we use an offset to align the popup properly – a bit to the right, and a bit down, so it won’t overlap the whole button.

Another think I would like to mention is that we will use a 9 patch background image for the popup, so it will look more fancy. But of course you can skip it and put any background you want, or no background at all.

Create layout/main.xml file and add a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#CCC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
   android:id="@+id/show_popup"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Show Popup" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new layout file: layout/popup_layout.xml that defines the layout of popup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/popup"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Popup"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="This is a simple popup" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/close"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And now the most interesting part. Open the TestPopupActivity and fill it with below code. Carefully read the comments to understand what’s going on.

```
 public class TestPopupActivity extends Activity {

//The "x" and "y" position of the "Show Button" on screen.
Point p;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
   btn_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {

       //Open popup window
       if (p != null)
       showPopup(TestPopupActivity.this, p);
     }
   });
}

// Get the x and y position after the button is draw on screen
// (It's important to note that we can't get the position in the onCreate(),
// because at that stage most probably the view isn't drawn yet, so it will return (0, 0))
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

   int[] location = new int[2];
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);

   // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
   // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
   button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

   //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
   p = new Point();
   p.x = location[0];
   p.y = location[1];
}

// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
   int popupWidth = 200;
   int popupHeight = 150;

   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 30;
   int OFFSET_Y = 30;

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       popup.dismiss();
     }
   });
}
}
```