# How to show an Activity as pop-up window on other Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a ListActivity  act as dialog. It's fine. when i select item click show another listactivity as dialog. But i want to show second listactivity as pop up window based activity. Already i have set manifest file  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog". Two list activity show but pop up windows not indicate specific item. is it possible we can do?   Already have this question in stackoverflow.  I know some code are missed. what are the steps. pls help me. Advanced thanks,

Comment: why not using fragments

Comment: fragment can show  two list dialog activity. how to do pop up window d

Comment: may be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867029/how-to-show-pop-up-window-in-android

Comment: where i can place it. such as oncreate, on start.

Comment: how to show either side.

Answer (score 0):

Android activity can create as dialog and.  activity can run single screen only. multiple activity  run on fragment only. you can't make popup window as a activity.

Answer (score 0):

Set below property in manifest for the activity which you want to be open as dialog:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```