# One time Password Reset Screen

Tags: android

I am designing a android application in which I wanted that END-USER when install application for first time should get a pop-up of reset password screen for one time only (aka Fresh Installation) and stored data on database through API.

I known shared preference is used but I want to know how to set it through API on database and also want to known how popup of screen is show.

Comment: can u provide any link for studying this thing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few links to get you started.

To make a custom dialog:
[How to show pop up window in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867029/how-to-show-pop-up-window-in-android/18867276#18867276)

To User SharedPreferences:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/2027644

And this is a good tutorial about using SQLite in android:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html