# How to display an image as a message in an Alert Dialog box?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm making a `listview` of marvel heroes that has an image, their real name and their superhero name. And every time I click a character in the list, I want to display an alert dialog box that will look like this without creating a custom layout?

PS: I'm a student and our instructor clearly instructed us not to create a custom layout.

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to achieve the image snippet above? Thanks! I have tried putting `setIcon` but it will just show the image as an icon on the upper left side of the box.

Here is my code so far:

MainActivity.java

```
<-- start of snippet -->

lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, list);

list.add(new Characters(R.drawable.thor, "Ordinson, Thor", "Thor"));
list.add(new Characters(R.drawable.steve, "Rogers, Steve", "Captain America"));
list.add(new Characters(R.drawable.stark, "Stark, Tony", "Ironman"));

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setNeutralButton("Okay", null);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


@Override
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
     Characters selectedCharacters = this.list.get(position);

     int image = selectedCharacters.getImg();
     String name = selectedCharacters.getName();
     String supername = selectedCharacters.getSupername();

     ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
     iv.setImageResource(image);

     builder.setTitle("" +name+ "\n" +supername);
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
}

<-- end of snippet -->
```

Comment: Create a [Custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867029/how-to-create-custom-alert-dialog-in-android) .. Use a `RecyclerView` if you want list ..

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately our instructor told us not to create a custom dialog. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setView()` to add the `ImageView` inside your `AlertDialog` like this:

```
@Override
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
     Characters selectedCharacters = this.list.get(position);

     int image = selectedCharacters.getImg();
     String name = selectedCharacters.getName();
     String supername = selectedCharacters.getSupername();
     ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
     iv.setImageResource(image);
     builder.setTitle("" +name+ "\n" +supername);
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     builder.setView(iv)
     dialog.show();
}
```

For the reference, head over to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)) of the documentation.